# Printing Fibonacci series using Recursion

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci, function-definition, storage-duration

```
//assume (main function)

int fibonacci(int a,int b){

    //int i inifinite loop(why?)
    static int i=1;

    if(i==terms){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        int c;

        c=a+b;
        a=b;
        b=c;

        printf(" %d ",c);
        i++;

        fibonacci(a,b);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

If I declare `i` variable in fibonacci function (definition function) it prints infinite loop of garbage values instead I used static `i` variable then the code prints Fibonacci series, please explain me how the statics variable works in this code?

Comment: Your regular int variable is scoped to the current fibonacci function. 
If you increment it and then call another fibonacci function via recursion, that new function has its own scope, thus a new int variable. 
A locally declared variable is only available in its context, in this case, the fibonacci function.

Comment: What is "terms"?

Comment: @Dominique: It appears the length of sequence OP intends to print.

Comment: @WedaPashi: are you talking about a global variable? That's generally a very bad idea.

Comment: As an aside, using recursion to compute Fibonacci numbers is a generally bad and unnecessary idea.  There are problems which recursion is great for, but the Fibonacci sequence isn't one of them.

Comment: @Dominique: Yeah, it's a bad idea. Agreed, but thats what OP came up with. May be OP can pass it as an argument to the function itself. -- if OP doesn't want to change the design to a greater extent. I'd never use recursion for such stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the variable `i` as having automatic storage duration

```
int fibonacci(int a,int b){

    //int i inifinite loop(why?)
    int i=1;
    //...
```

then in each recursive call of the function the variable `i` is initialized anew by the value `1` and you have an infinite loop of recursive calls.

When you declare the variable `i` as having static storage duration

```
int fibonacci(int a,int b){

    //int i inifinite loop(why?)
    static int i=1;
    //...
```

then it is initialized only once before the program starts.

In any case your function is incorrect because even if the variable `i` is declared as having static storage duration it is not reset to its initial value after recursive function calls. And moreover it is a bad  approach when a function depends on a global variable as your function depends on the global variable `terms`.

Moreover the Fibonacci series is a fixed series. The user should not specify the variables `a` and `b`. It should specify for the function the index of the number in the series that he is going to obtain. And the function should return this number instead of returning 0.

For example the function could be defined the following way

```
unsigned long long int fibonacci( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci( n - 1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 );
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int fibonacci( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci( n - 1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 );
}

int main()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf( "%u -> %llu\n", i, fibonacci( i ) );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 1
3 -> 2
4 -> 3
5 -> 5
6 -> 8
7 -> 13
8 -> 21
9 -> 34
```